# Connecting to a remote mongoDB server

Tags: mongodb, remote-access

I have a remote machine which I connect to using SSH, I installed mongoDB on it, and I wish to use it remotely, how do I connect to it using nodejs and mongoDB compass? the localhost is the IP ?

```
const db = "mongodb://what do I write here?";
const connectDB = async () => {
  try {
    await mongoose.connect(db, { useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true });
    console.log("MongoDB Connected...");
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    process.exit(1);
  }
};
connectDB();
```

Comment: the machine has which os?

Comment: @PrashantPokhriyal machine is ubuntu OS

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### Short answer

Login to your machine, open mongodb configuration file located at `/etc/mongod.conf`  and change the `bindIp` field to your machine ip address (it is the same ip address which you are using to ssh to your machine), after that restart mongodb server.

---

#### Detailed answer

- Open `/etc/mongod.conf` file using any of the editor, if you are running a desktop version then you can make use of `gedit` utility tool

  ```
    sudo gedit /etc/mongod.conf
  ```

If you are running a server version, then you can make use of [vi editor](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/vi-editor-unix/) command

```
    sudo vi /etc/mongod.conf
```

- The file should contain the following kind of content:

  ```
    systemLog:
        destination: file
        path: "/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log"
        logAppend: true
    storage:
        journal:
            enabled: true
    processManagement:
        fork: true
    net:
        bindIp: 127.0.0.1  // enter your ip address here
        port: 27017
    setParameter:
        enableLocalhostAuthBypass: false
  ```
- Once you change the `bindIp`, then you have to restart the mongodb, using the following command

  ```
    sudo service mongod restart
  ```
- Now you'll be able to connect to the mongodb server, with the same ip address which you are using to ssh to your system.

  ```
    mongoose.connect('mongodb://<machine_ip_address>:27017/<database_name>')
  ```

Comment: cat /etc/mongod.conf how do I access this file? I installed the mongoDB using sudo apt install -y mongodb, when I use your command it says file not found

Comment: @AlexK, you can open it with any of your favorite editor. If you are familiar with **vi editor**, then you have to run following command to edit the file: `sudo vi /etc/mongod.conf` and if you are running a desktop version then you can run following command: `sudo gedit /etc/mongod.conf`

Answer (score 3):

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://username:password@host:port/database')
```

Now for the `host`, is there any hostname or IP you could use?

Comment: but what username and password?

Comment: if you don't have any, you can try and skip those, mongodb://host:port/database ?

Comment: I tried it , didnt work, my machine is ubuntu OS, what host should I put there? the IP adress?

Comment: run `ipconfig getifaddr en0` and use that ip

Comment: do a `ping {ip}` on it from you client, just to make sure it is accessible

Comment: Command 'ipconfig' not found, did you mean:

  command 'iwconfig' from deb wireless-tools
  command 'ifconfig' from deb net-tools
  command 'iconfig' from deb ipmiutil
 this is the response.

Comment: `ifconfig | grep "inet " | grep -v 127.0.0.1 | cut -d\  -f2`

Comment: the command doesnt work 
cut: the delimiter must be a single character
Try 'cut --help' for more information.

Answer (score 2):

first try this : `mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/database')`

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://<machine_ip_address>:27017/<database_name>')
```

> mongodb://[username:password@]host1[:port1][,...hostN[:portN]][/[database][?options]]

check https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/

Comment: yea the problem that its not localhost, its remote, how do I know which parameters I put there?

Comment: add ip address instead of localhost

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/<database-name>", { useNewUrlParser: true });
const db = mongoose.connection
db.on('error', (error) => console.error(error));
db.once('open', () => console.log('Connected to Database'));
```

Make sure to run MongoDB

> mongod --config /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf

Answer (score 2):

If you are using MongoDb Compass

1. Open 27017 port in Inbound of your Server
2. Form a link just like mongodb://11.11.111.11 in case you are not going to use auth
3. Click Connect

Basicly the link is mongodb://[username:password@]host1[:port1][,...hostN[:portN]][/[defaultauthdb][?options]]

More information [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/)