# Unable to create MongoDB database using Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to run the below program to create a mongo database using Node.js by running `node app.js`.

**app.js**

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://hostname:27017/mydb";

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Database created!");
  db.close();
});
```

Below is the error I'm getting :-

```
(node:20815) DeprecationWarning: current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.

MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [hostname_fqdn:27017] on first connect [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 10.127.45.59:27017
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1134:16) {
  name: 'MongoNetworkError'
}]
    at Pool.<anonymous> (/root/myfolder/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/topologies/server.js:438:11)
    at Pool.emit (events.js:223:5)
    at /root/myfolder/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:562:14
    at /root/myfolder/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:995:11
    at /root/myfolder/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:32:7
    at callback (/root/myfolder/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:280:5)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/root/myfolder/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:310:7)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:313:26)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:223:5)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8) {
  name: 'MongoNetworkError'
}
```

The file/node_modules/package.json all are located in a CentOS Virtual Machine.

Comment: it seems like you have either an incorrect url or not running database.

Comment: Do you have mongodb installed and running on hostname:27017 ?

Comment: Mongo is running as I am able to manually create a database/collection.
I have installed mongodb on top of a CentOS VM.

Comment: `hostname` is a just a dummy host I have provided in SO. I have entered the FQDN as the hostname. And MongoDB is running of hostname:27017

Comment: I have created user in admin db however I am unable to connect to MongoDB by giving creds using MongoDB Compass

Comment: If the mongodb server is running on a different machine, you need to enable outside connections: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58323458/connecting-to-a-remote-mongodb-server

Answer (score 0):

You need to start the MongoDB Service after installing.

Edited:

If you have already started service and connecting mongo via terminal, then try to remove mongo lock file (rm /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock) and repair mongod (mongod -–repair). Now start mongo service and see if you can connect. I had similar issue with EC2 and Compass and tried above to resolve.

Comment: `sudo systemctl start mongod
sudo systemctl daemon-reload`
I have used the above to start mongodb services

Comment: after the above commands, did you tried mongo command on terminal? to see if you can connect.

Comment: Yes, mongo terminal is working fine on the VM. Not sure why I am not able to connect to MongoDB from outside the VM.

Comment: did you get time to check - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41318354/mongodb-failed-to-connect-to-server-on-first-connect